# android get date of up coming Sunday

Tags: android, date

I am using following code to get date of coming Sunday. Code is working in some devices but in some devices it shows Sunday after coming Sunday. Please help. why it is not working in some devices.

```
try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
            c.add(Calendar.DATE,7);

            Date currentTime = c.getTime();
            date = dateFormat.format(currentTime);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: For a date like Monday 6th of March 2017, would you expect the coming Sunday to be the 12th or the 19th?

Comment: Coming Sunday to be 12th

Comment: Then it depends on what day you think the week starts on. If the week starts on Monday in the example above, then setting the `DAY_OF_WEEK` to `SUNDAY` would set it to the 12th, and then adding 7 days to that would give you the 19th.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Calendar getNextSundayDate() {
        Calendar calendarForNextSunday = Calendar.getInstance();
        int today = calendarForNextSunday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        //System.out.println("today" + today);
        if (today != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            int offset = Calendar.SATURDAY - today + Calendar.SUNDAY;
            //System.out.println("offset" + offset);
            calendarForNextSunday.add(Calendar.DATE, offset);
            //System.out.println("new" + calendarForNextSunday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            //System.out.println("next sunday" + calendarForNextSunday.get(Calendar.DATE));
        }
        return calendarForNextSunday;
    }
```

This might work for you

Answer (score 0):

may be the problem of TimeZone ?
try this:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("some time zone"));
```

Comment: Devices having same timezone gives different dates